# Repeated Dates in Rows

Tags: date, gridview, rows

I have grid view.It contain date columns. I dont want to show repeat date in all the rows.
I mean i have to show on top once.

Please see my grid below. On Date Added column i want to show date only once if it is same date added.

```
Date Added Who Added Updated Who Updated Action Code Comment 
Edit 02/05/01 UTA  02/05/01 UTA  008  COMMENT ASSOCIATED WITH MAIL ACTION.

Edit 02/05/01 UTA  02/05/01 UTA  309  STATUS ACTION COMMENT.

Edit 02/05/01 UTA  01/05/10 DLG   COVERAGE RELATED.HELLO RAVI.HELLO RAVI.HELLO RAVI.
ELLO RAVI.HELLO RAVI.HELLO RAVI.HELLO RAVI.HELLO
```

Comment: You need to provide much more information that this. What langauge are you using? Which grid view widget? Where does the data come from?

Comment: @Ravi: Please edit your question and format your data properly. You should get good results by selecting the rows with data and pressing the "Code Sample" button. Use the preview to check if it looks fine. And you should change your tags to what program/language you are referring to, maybe Excel or a database you use. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: fix your table format. Try using: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables